# Change the width of div to fit the content after absolutely positioned

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to make a dropdown menu

In order to hide the sub menu before the hovering, I set my .dropdown-content `display: none;` 
And because I set `position: absolute;`so the div is shrinked, but I want the width of the sub menu to fit the size of the content. I know `display: inline-block;` can make block element to fit the size of the content, but how can solve this situation? Please help me, I'll really appreciate!

```css
nav.dropdown-nav {
  background: #000000;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;    /**/
  display: -weblit-flex;
}
nav.dropdown-nav>li {
  position: relative;
}
nav.dropdown-nav>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: block;
}
div.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute; /**/
  top: 60px;
  background: #333333;
  opacity: 0.9;
  padding: 0 30px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}
div.dropdown-content a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: block;
}
nav.dropdown-nav>li:hover>a {
  color: #B3B3B3;
}
nav.dropdown-nav>li:hover div.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
div.dropdown-content li:hover a {
  color: #B3B3B3;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/basic.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nav-style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="dropdown-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#">WOMEN</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bags & Purses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blazers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Coats & Jackets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dresses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hoodies & Sweatshirts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">MEN</a>
      </li>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you post the CSS you have used for this too

Comment: Giving a css, or even better giving a fiddle would help a lot, understanding and fixing the problem

Comment: @matthewelsom Because my text in the `.dropdown-content a` is too long, it exceed the div after adding `white-space: nowrap;` :(

Comment: @hayley - you will have to show us the issue.. your comment doesn't make sense without seeing the code and the issue in a fiddle.

Comment: @matthewelsom I just made the fiddle. Sorry, I am not very familiar with it...

Comment: @hayley - ok thanks, so what are you trying to achieve? You want the sub menu items to always be the same width as the main menu item?

Comment: @matthewelsom No, I want the sub menu items will never wrap, and the width of the sub menu will fit the with the items.

Comment: @hayley See my answer below. The issue you have is that your div.dropdown-content is set to 100%... you need to set that to auto, and then the white-space: nowrap; will work

Comment: @matthewelsom Thanks a lot! I did't notice that........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the sub menu width by the length of the sub menu items.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.dropdown-nav > li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  background: aliceblue;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: salmon;
  width: auto; /* This will make the sub menu auto fit it's content */
}
.dropdown-content a{
  white-space: nowrap; /* This will stop the long sub items from wrapping */
}
.dropdown-menu:hover ~ .dropdown-content,
.dropdown-content:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="dropdown-nav">
  <li>
    <a class="dropdown-menu" href="#">WOMEN</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Accessories Accessories Accessories Accessories </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bags & Purses</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">MEN</a>
    
  </li>
</nav>
```

Your code sample:

```css
nav.dropdown-nav {
 background: #000000;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: flex;    /**/
 display: -weblit-flex;
}
nav.dropdown-nav>li {
 position: relative;
}
nav.dropdown-nav>li>a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
 padding: 12px 30px;
 margin: 8px 0;
 display: block;
}
div.dropdown-content {
 position: absolute; /**/
 top: 60px;
 background: #333333;
 opacity: 0.9;
 padding: 0 30px;
 display: none;
 width: auto;
}
div.dropdown-content a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 padding: 10px 0;
 display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
nav.dropdown-nav>li:hover>a {
 color: #B3B3B3;
}
nav.dropdown-nav>li:hover div.dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
div.dropdown-content li:hover a {
 color: #B3B3B3;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/basic.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nav-style.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <nav class="dropdown-nav">
  <li>
   <a href="#">WOMEN</a>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Bags & Purses</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Blazers</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Coats & Jackets</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Dresses</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Hoodies & Sweatshirts</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">MEN</a>
  </li>
 </nav>
</body>
</html>
```